# Using collapse in listview items not removing the space for particular item view entirely

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

- In listview items I'm using `Visiblity` concept in layout to perform
  visible and collapse. When performing `Collapse`, listview items not
  removing that view entirely from the layout.
- It is removing the item contents such as name and id but
  placing blank white view at that particular listitem position in
  listview.
- Below I have shared the codes for better understanding:

**StudentData.ts :**

```
export class StudentData {

constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public collapseData: boolean) {}

}
```

**student.page.html:**

```
 <ListView id="listId" [items]="allFeedItems" class="list-group" height="300">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout [visibility]="item.collapseData ? 'visible' : 'collapse'" >

                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label class="item-address" text="address"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
                .....

            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
```

**What is happening:**

For eg: in modal class, I'm saving switch control values for listitems in hashmap. when coming back to my main page (i.e)StudentPage, I need to hide the particular row item entirely. But it is removing only the contents name and id. It's not removing the blank view for that particular listview item position.

**What I'm expecting :**

To remove the blank view for that particular item position in listview.

Comment: `ng-template` ---> `ng-container` or move your let-item into <StackLayout>

Comment: @Z.Bagley getting error let is only supported in template elements

Comment: That's my bad, not used to using let-item much. The general problem is that 'ng-template' is built into the DOM. Adding [hidden]="!item.collapseData" should do the trick (or just "item.collapseData")

Comment: @Z.Bagley hidden doesn't worked for me.it doesn't remove the view entirely.Same issue occurred again.

Comment: Showing what's rendered to DOM might help

Comment: @Steve did u try with renderer2 .its the last thing you can try if ng-template or hidden dosent work

Comment: Hi @Steve, did you check if the item is influenced by a CSS style? like a display: block property or something related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned in the comment by [dashman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834337/how-do-hide-a-layout-and-included-views). I have added the visibility inside the child stacklayout instead of parent stacklayout. Then it doesn't took the blank white space for the particular listitem.

```
<ng-template let-item="item">
  <StackLayout>

    <StackLayout [visibility]="item.collapseData ? 'visible' : 'collapse'" orientation="horizontal">
      <Label class="item-address" text="address"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    .....

  </StackLayout>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should Use different templates for that -

```
<ListView [items]="items" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector">
<template nsTemplateKey="big" let-item="item">
<!-- big item template -->
</template>
<template nsTemplateKey="small" let-item="item">
<!-- small item with image -->
</template>
<template nsTemplateKey="small-no-image" let-item="item">
<!-- small item with no image -->
</template>
</ListView>
```

and TS code -

```
public templateSelector(item: NewsItem, index: number, items: 
NewsItem[]) {
if (item.type === "big") {
return "big"
} 

if (item.type === "small" && item.imageUrl) {
return "small";
}
if (item.type === "small" && item.imageUrl) {
return "small-no-image";
}

throw new Error("Unrecognized template!")
}
```

for more Info Read Here - https://medium.com/@alexander.vakrilov/faster-nativescript-listview-with-multiple-item-templates-8f903a32e48f